fake and real moveit controllers at the same time
currently, I am trying to create motion plans for a real ur10e which has a Robotiq 2f-140 gripper attached. I have successfully integrated the gripper and the robot using the moveit assistant. I can generate plans for the arm, but I still don't have a functional way to plan for the real gripper on moveit ( if someone knows how to do it please tell me ;)). Therefore, I wanted to use a fake controller (interpolated) so I have a basic "simulation" of the gripper being opened or closed. Now, I am able to create plans independently for the real robot, and also I am able to create plans for the fake gripper (also publishing fake joint states), but have failed to mixed them both. It seems to me that only one moveit_controller_manager can be defined at once, so I got errors when launching a launch file with and only the last defined manager would work:
<param name="moveit_controller_manager" value="moveit_fake_controller_manager/MoveItFakeControllerManager"/>
<param name="moveit_controller_manager" value="moveit_simple_controller_manager/MoveItSimpleControllerManager"/>

So the question is, if having fake controllers and real ones running at the same time is even possible in moveit and if so how. These are my config files:
fake_controllers.yaml:
controller_list:
  - name: fake_gripper_controller
    type: interpolated
    joints:
      - gripper_finger_joint

initial: # Define initial robot poses.
  - group: gripper
    pose: close

ros_controllers.yaml:
controller_list:
  - name: scaled_pos_joint_traj_controller
    action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
    default: True
    type: FollowJointTrajectory
    joints:
      - shoulder_pan_joint
      - shoulder_lift_joint
      - elbow_joint
      - wrist_1_joint
      - wrist_2_joint
      - wrist_3_joint


If you write a single YAML file that includes both the real robot controller and the fake gripper controller, then your single controller manager should load and run those two controllers.
A controller manager's job is to load multiple ROS Control controllers, broker shared memory communication among them, and makes sure hardware interfaces only get claimed once. It's designed to load multiple controllers and as long as the resources they demand don't conflict, it's no problem to load whatever combination you choose.
I'm pretty sure I've done this before in ROS 2 for similar purposes, when I was using URSim and so needed to use the real robot driver, but didn't otherwise have a gripper simulator besides the fake controller.

Hi, Thanks for your comment. Are you talking about something similar to the controllers.yaml file? Do you have an example of such file?. I think I recently tried such an approach, with MoveItSimpleControllerManager and a YAML file that contained the real controller and the fake interpolated gripper controller, but without success. Maybe I am still doing something wrong.
